# After accidentally changing the difficulty and reloading, can I still get the "Destiny Dominated" trophy?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I play Reckoning: KoA on the PS3. I am playing the game on hard difficulty for the "Destiny Dominated" trophy, but I changed the difficulty accidentally due to the sudden popup screen which asked me to change the difficulty after a few deaths. I unintentionally clicked "yes", but then reloaded the game as I read that the trophy won't show up if you change the difficulty during the game.

**Does the trophy show up anyway or do I have to start the game all over again?**

Comment: I think you should be safe as long as you don't actually save the game after making the switch.  Just load your previous save and continue on and it will be like it never happened.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest.  On a related note, I hate those change of difficulty pop ups with a fiery passion.

Answer (score 1):

Now I can answer this question by myself for sure. YES, the trophy will show up! Do what I did (simply reload the game after accidentally change) and go on. Then it will be like it never happened. And don't be feared! The trophy needs almost 10 seconds to show up. Have fun!